# Entity in a library used by other spring boot apps

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a spring boot 3 application.

I need to create a library who will be used by two other spring boot apps.

Theses spring boot apps will have their own entity, repository but the library will also have some entity and repository.

Is there a possibility to specify another source of entity for a spring boot apps?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your library has base package **"package.b"** and these applications will have different base packages (for example **"package.a"**), configuration will be something like:

```
package package.a;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"package.a.model.entity", "package.b.model.entity"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"package.a.repo", "package.b.repo"})

public class ApplicationThatUsesYourLib {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApplicationThatUsesYourLib.class, args);
    }

}
```